# A question about convergence in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I have been working on this question for a while now, and I would really like to get some help.

Let $(X,\mathscr{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset A_3 \cdots$ be an increasing sequence of measurable sets such that $\mu(A_i)< \infty$ for every $i = 1,2,\cdots $ Denote $A=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$. Prove that $\mathbb{1}_{A_i} \xrightarrow{measure} \mathbb{1}_{A}$ if and only if $\mu(A) < \infty$.

My current approach is using the fact that $\mu(A) \leq \lim_{t\xrightarrow{}\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{T}\mu(A_i)< T\mu(A_T) <\infty$ for the first direction. But it is not so clear how should we approach the reverse direction.

Thanks!

Comment: By $\mathbb{1}_{A_i} \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{1}_{A}$, do you mean convergence in measure?

Comment: @Ramiro yes, I meant the first function convergent to the second function in measure. Good catch, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your argument, since it looks like your captial "$T$" should be tending to $\infty$.

Suppose $\mu(A)<\infty$.  Then for any $\varepsilon>0$, by Markov's inequality, $$\mu(|\mathbb 1_{A}-\mathbb 1_{A_n}|>\varepsilon) \leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int |\mathbb 1_{A}-\mathbb 1_{A_n}|d\mu $$$$=\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int \mathbb 1_{A}-\mathbb 1_{A_n}d\mu = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\mu(A\setminus A_n)\to 0,$$ as $n\to\infty$.

Now, suppose $\mathbb 1_{A_n}\stackrel{measure}\to \mathbb 1_A$.  Since
$$\mathbb 1_{A}(x)-\mathbb 1_{A_n}(x)
=\begin{cases}
1& x\in A\setminus A_n\\
0& x\in A_n \cup A^c
\end{cases}
$$

Then for any $\varepsilon \in(0,1)$, $x\in\{|\mathbb 1_{A}-\mathbb 1_{A_n}|>\varepsilon\}$ if and only if $x\in A\setminus A_n$, i.e. $\{|\mathbb 1_{A}-\mathbb 1_{A_n}|>\varepsilon\}=A\setminus A_n$.  So,

$$
\mu(A) = \mu(A_n) + \mu(A\setminus A_n) = \mu(A_n) + \mu(|\mathbb 1_{A}-\mathbb 1_{A_n}|>\varepsilon)<\infty,
$$
since $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ and $\mu(|\mathbb 1_{A}-\mathbb 1_{A_n}|>\varepsilon)\to 0$.